# swift: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value in awakeFromNib()

Tags: ios, swift

I probably just missed something, but for the life of me, I can't figure it out.

I'm working on an app with an MVC structure; I place all the needed fields on the Xib, but I rely on a View to actually change font, size, etc.

Here's my code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

protocol ProductionWellChemistryFormTwoViewDelegate {

}

class ProductionWellChemistryFormTwoView: BaseUIView {

    let fontSizeL : CGFloat = 18
    let fontName : String = "Futura"
    var delegate : ProductionWellChemistryFormTwoViewDelegate!

    @IBOutlet weak var labelTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelFieldCode: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelGasFlaskNo: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelDatePrepared: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelDateVacuumed: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelClickingSound: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelTimeStarted: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelTimeFinished: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelWHPStarted: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelWHPEnded: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelSPPStarted: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelSPPEnded: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelSPStarted: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelSPEnded: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelRemarks: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var textfieldFieldCode: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textfieldGasFlaskNo: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textfieldDatePrepared: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textfieldDateVacuumed: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textfieldTimeStarted: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textfieldTimeFinished: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textfieldWHPStarted: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textfieldWHPEnded: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textfieldSPPStarted: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textfieldSPPEnded: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textfieldSPStarted: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textfieldSPEnded: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textviewRemarks: UITextView!

    @IBOutlet weak var switchClickSound: UISwitch!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.labelTitle.font = UIFont(name: self.fontName, size: self.fontSizeL)
        self.labelFieldCode.font = UIFont(name: self.fontName, size: self.fontSizeL)
        self.labelGasFlaskNo.font = UIFont(name: self.fontName, size: self.fontSizeL)
        self.labelDatePrepared.font = UIFont(name: self.fontName, size: self.fontSizeL)
        self.labelDateVacuumed.font = UIFont(name: self.fontName, size: self.fontSizeL)
        self.labelClickingSound.font = UIFont(name: self.fontName, size: self.fontSizeL)
        self.labelTimeStarted.font = UIFont(name: self.fontName, size: self.fontSizeL)
        self.labelTimeFinished.font = UIFont(name: self.fontName, size: self.fontSizeL)
        self.labelWHPStarted.font = UIFont(name: self.fontName, size: self.fontSizeL)
        self.labelWHPEnded.font = UIFont(name: self.fontName, size: self.fontSizeL)
        self.labelSPPStarted.font = UIFont(name: self.fontName, size: self.fontSizeL)
        self.labelSPPEnded.font = UIFont(name: self.fontName, size: self.fontSizeL)
        self.labelSPStarted.font = UIFont(name: self.fontName, size: self.fontSizeL)
        self.labelSPEnded.font = UIFont(name: self.fontName, size: self.fontSizeL)
        self.labelRemarks.font = UIFont(name: self.fontName, size: self.fontSizeL)

        self.textfieldFieldCode.font = UIFont(name: self.fontName, size: self.fontSizeL)
        self.textfieldGasFlaskNo.font = UIFont(name: self.fontName, size: self.fontSizeL)
        self.textfieldDatePrepared.font = UIFont(name: self.fontName, size: self.fontSizeL)
        self.textfieldDateVacuumed.font = UIFont(name: self.fontName, size: self.fontSizeL)
        self.textfieldTimeStarted.font = UIFont(name: self.fontName, size: self.fontSizeL)
        self.textfieldTimeFinished.font = UIFont(name: self.fontName, size: self.fontSizeL)
        self.textfieldWHPStarted.font = UIFont(name: self.fontName, size: self.fontSizeL)
        self.textfieldWHPEnded.font = UIFont(name: self.fontName, size: self.fontSizeL)
        self.textfieldSPPStarted.font = UIFont(name: self.fontName, size: self.fontSizeL)
        self.textfieldSPPEnded.font = UIFont(name: self.fontName, size: self.fontSizeL)
        self.textfieldSPStarted.font = UIFont(name: self.fontName, size: self.fontSizeL)
        self.textfieldSPEnded.font = UIFont(name: self.fontName, size: self.fontSizeL)
        self.textviewRemarks.font = UIFont(name: self.fontName, size: self.fontSizeL)
        self.textviewRemarks.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        self.textviewRemarks.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        self.textviewRemarks.text = ""
    }
}
```

The code throws the exception when I read the first line of `awakeFromNib()`, whatever that is (I tried commenting out the first line, so it went to the second).

I've done this about a dozen or so times total, so I'm really not sure what's happening. The only thing I can think of that I did differently was try to fix a previous `Unknown class in Interface Builder file` by going into the Xib's source code and renaming a class `ProductionWellChemistryFormTwoViewer`, an  erroneously named class which I then renamed to my class now (no er past View).

The app runs if I disable everything inside the `awakeFromNib()`.

EDIT: The app also runs fine, fonts and all, if I change the following line in the XIB source code:

```
<view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="vYc-5l-gfD" userLabel="ContentView" customClass="ProductionWellChemistryFormTwoView" customModule="Integra_Geochemistry" customModuleProvider="target">
```

Back to:

```
<view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="vYc-5l-gfD" userLabel="ContentView" customClass="ProductionWellChemistryFormTwoViewer"  customModule="Integra_Geochemistry" customModuleProvider="target">
```

I get a `Unknown class _TtC20Integra_Geochemistry36ProductionWellChemistryFormTwoViewer in Interface Builder file.` error, but at least it works.

I'll expand on the situation I mentioned above, here's what happened:

1. I created the XIB.
2. I created the view, erroneously named `ProductionWellChemistryFormTwoViewer`
3. Set the XIB's class to said view.
4. Found out about the wrong name.
5. Changed name to `ProductionWellChemistryFormTwoView`. Some errors pop-up.
6. Manually changed any reference to `ProductionWellChemistryFormTwoViewer` to `ProductionWellChemistryFormTwoView`.
7. Noticed running the app produces the `unknown class` error, went into XIB source, removed `ProductionWellChemistryFormTwoViewer`.
8. THEN I got the errors above.

Comment: Oh gawd that's some inconvenient code right there...

Comment: I think you should add some more IBOutlets... (/sarcasm) but in all seriousness I would recommend you take a new approach to implementing this, this is a hellish nightmare at the moment. You should probably be using IBOutletCollections.

Comment: First of all it's pretty inefficient to create dozens of the same `UIFont` instance. Check if the font is `nil`.

Comment: also check that all outlets are connected.

Comment: Chances are that you forgot to bind an IBOutlet in interface builder.

Comment: @Ramy Al Zuhouri, opening the xib and the view side-by-side shows little dots at the side of all the IBOutlets. I'm assuming that means they're all connected. Is `bind in interface builder` something else?

Comment: They're not necessarily connected, if you ever renamed a property.  You need to view the NIB connections in interface builder and see if any show `!` (or are not connected).

Comment: I'd say, post a screenshot of the connections but...

Comment: @PetahChristian, where can I see if any show `!`? Sorry, new to this, and I don't what's called what.

Comment: @originaluser2, tried you advice, and DerailedLogic's code below. Didn't work. Still crash on `awakeForNib()`.

Comment: @zack_falcon: there are far better quality image hosters than that one; have you seen the kind of adverts that are placed there? Not all of those are SFW.

Comment: I had the same issue but it works after moving the code from `awakeFromNib` to `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 1):

So in all likelihood you didn't link one of those IBOutlets.

With that many outlets its going to be confusing to figure out which one, so I suggest you take @originaluser2's suggestion and use IBCollections.

```
class ProductionWellChemistryFormTwoView: BaseUIView {
    let fontSizeL : CGFloat = 18
    let fontName : String = "Futura"
    var delegate : ProductionWellChemistryFormTwoViewDelegate!

    // By declaring the IBOutlet as an array it tells IB that its a collection
    @IBOutlet var labelCollection: [UILabel]! 
    @IBOutlet var textFieldCollection: [UITextField]!  

    @IBOutlet weak var textviewRemarks: UITextView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        let font = UIFont(name: self.fontName, size: self.fontSizeL)
        labelCollection.each{ $0.font = font }
        textFieldCollection.each{ $0.font = font }

        textviewRemarks.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        textviewRemarks.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        textviewRemarks.text = ""
    }   
}
```

Then go through your xib and connect all the outlets as needed.

Comment: I don't know why, but it says labelCollection has no function `each` - I had to resort to a for loop. Also, how am I supposed to access individual labels and textfields in my controller? I did just the labels, and commented out the textfields. Finally, it didn't work. Still crashing on `awakeForNib()`.

Comment: It's `labelCollection.forEach`

Comment: Sorry, like I said above, not too well-versed in Swift. In any case, it didn't work anyway, even if I did do it your way. I've updated my question above with some new findings. Perhaps they can help.